# Mschart multiple series with different value count (Changing xAxis interval)

Tags: c#, .net, charts, pdfsharp, migradoc

I need to save a Linechart as a .png, maybe even .svg file. 
A Dataset(date, value) and has 1800 values each. I'm able to save a very accurate .png, but, but the majorGridLines of the xAxis fill the entire chart area. Its practicaly completley black. 
I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; to create the chart btw.

[(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7RvC.png)

i tried to increase the xAxis interval by a 100 to only display 18 timestamps yet still all 1800 values, which did not work at all. 
Futhermore, i tried adding an additional series, containing only 18 values, making the line transparent and only making the x axis of the second series visible.
I also tried using MigraDoc / PDFSharp from NuGet to build a chart directly to a .pdf file. I did'nt find a way to do it there either. 
Or am i doing something horribly wrong??

I hope any of you has an idea of what im talking about!

```
public void createWinfromChart()
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Data> keyValue in obj)
            {
                chart1      = new Chart();
                chart1.Size = new Size(1000, 1000);
                addNewSeries(keyValue.Value.simplifyOutput(), keyValue.Key);
                cnt++;
                saveChartImage(cnt);
            }
        }
```

```
public void addNewSeries(Dictionary<string, float> dictionary, string tag)
        {
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            //xAchse
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            //yAchse
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval            = 100;

            Series series = new Series();

            //Series style
            series.ChartType       = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series.BorderWidth     = 2;
            series.Color           = Color.Green;
            series.IsXValueIndexed = false;

            foreach (float values in obj[tag].value)
            {
                series.Points.AddY(values);
            }

            chart1.Series.Add(series);
            ChartArea chartArea2 = new ChartArea();
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);
            chart1.ChartAreas[1].Axes[0].MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas[1].Axes[1].MajorGrid.Enabled = true;

            Series series2 = new Series();
            series2.ChartType       = SeriesChartType.Line;
            series2.BorderWidth     = 0;
            series2.Color           = Color.Transparent;
            series2.IsXValueIndexed = false;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, float> valuePair in dictionary)
            {
                series2.Points.AddXY(valuePair.Key, 0);
            }

            chart1.Series.Add(series2);
        }
```